# export Wordpress events into a Facebook page

Tags: facebook, wordpress, events

Using "All-in-One Event Calendar" by Timely to export the events on a Wordpress blog into a Facebook page.  I have the Facebook feed connected, but the events posted into my personal profile.  How can I have them just go to the specific page?

Answer (score 1):

According to Time.ly, the creators of the plugin, event export to page is supported only in the Pro version. Quote from [bailly](http://community.time.ly/member/2-bailly), an administrator of the forum:

> Although it seems like a simple feature, it is actually a very complex addition.
>
> We believe that this is a feature above and beyond what most regular users will
>   need from a calendar. In addition, it helps us pay for the development team to
>   continue to improve the software and all the features that are asked of us.

Link to the complete discussion thread:

http://community.time.ly/forum/troubleshooting/importing-and-exporting-events/316-export-to-facebook-community-page-instead-of-facebook-user

Comment: I thought that the one line summary was sufficient. I updated the answer to play with formatting a bit. Does this meet your approval now?